# For which values of c this time complexity equation is valid : $n^{1+c}$ = O(nlogn)

Tags: algorithms

For which values of c this equation holds : $n^{1+c}$  = O(nlogn)

i tried giving them big numbers but still $n^{1+c}$ came out bigger even when i gave c something like 0.1 ?

but a book that I'm reading says that this equation : $n^{1+c}$  = O(nlogn) holds for some values of c where **c > 0** ?

Comment: Hint: For the case $n^{1+c}$, consider the inequality $n^{1+c}\le a.nlog(n)$, where $a$ is a constant. Consider the limit $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c>0$, then $$n^{1+c}\neq O(n\log n).$$

This is because, if $c>0$, $$n^c\neq O(\log n)$$

Comment: Could you please clarify your second statement? At the very least, shouldn't it hold true for $0\le c\le 1$?

Comment: I'm sorry i didnt get the second part, could you please clarify that a bit?

Comment: Yes, probably what was meant

Comment: @RobertZ Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: @EdaiBossinShid I fixed my statement, it was wrong before.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\log(x)}x=0$

And for any $\epsilon>0\quad $ we get $\quad \dfrac{\log(n)}{n^\epsilon}=\dfrac{\epsilon\log(n)}{\epsilon\,n^\epsilon}=\dfrac 1\epsilon\dfrac{\log(n^\epsilon)}{n^\epsilon}\to 0$

So the logarithm is negligible before any power of $n$ : $\quad\log(n)\ll n^\epsilon$ when $n\gg 1$.

Thus $\forall \epsilon>0,\ n\log(n)=o(n^{1+\epsilon})$ and compare it to $n^{1+c}$ where $c$ is fixed.

This means that $\dfrac{n\log(n)}{n^{1+c}}\to 0$ and we cannot have $\require{cancel}\cancel{n^{1+c}=O(n\log(n))}$

---

Although in practical circumstances, $n$ is never infinite, and if you know a boundary $n<N$ for your problem (e.g. you have to compare two algorithms and you know in advance the maximum size of your input)

then it makes sense to search for which $c$ does $N^{1+c}=O(N\log N)$? (although it is a bit of abusing notations, let say for which $c$ does $N^{1+c}\ll N\log N$)

And you find a critical value $c=\dfrac{\log\log N}{\log N}$

For instance let's take $N=1\,000\,000$ we find $c\approx 0.19$

Best comparison sorts are known to operate in $n\log n$ time, while shell sort with best sequence increments is known to operate in $n^{1.2}\approx n^{1+c}$.

Thus for input sizes smaller than a million, shell sort will be theoretically more efficient.